# Pass parameter with import, but it override the export in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass parameter into packages with import but it override my export.  I saw some suggested $main:debugLevel in Debugger.pm but it doesn't work.  How to fix this?

main.pl

```
our $debugLevel = 5;  
our $dDebug=TRUE;
our $dPkg=__PACKAGE__;
our $dMsg="";

use MyPkg::Debugger qw( :all );
# ^-- how do I pass in the variables declared above?
...

dPrintLog(4, 'testsub', 'msg', $mydata);
# ^-- this generate error, if i put in the "import" sub in the Debugger.pm
```

Debugger.pm

```
use strict;
package MyPkg::Debugger;

our $VERSION     = 1.00;
our @ISA         = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw(dPrintLog );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
                     all => \@EXPORT_OK
                   );

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Data::Dumper;

our $debugLevel = 5;  
our $dDebug=TRUE;
our $dPkg=__PACKAGE__;
our $dMsg="";

sub import {
   my ($debugLevel , $dDebug, $dMsg, $data) = @_;
}

sub dPrintLog {
     my ($level, $sub, $msg, $data) = @_;
     if ($level == 5) {
          print "L:" . $level . ";" . "Pkg:" . $sub . ";". "Msg: " . $msg . "\n";
          print '   '.Dumper($data) unless (!defined $data);   
     }elsif ($level == 3){
     }elsif ($level == 1){
     }else{
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Exporter)'s documentation carefully. It contains all the information you need.

App.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use MyDbg (':all', 5); # Try removing the 5.

dPrintLog(undef, 'message');
```

MyDbg.pm

```
package MyDbg;
use warnings;
use strict;


our @ISA         = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK   = qw(dPrintLog );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( all => \@EXPORT_OK );
use Exporter ();

my $debugLevel = 3;  

sub import {
    my ($class, $tag, $level) = @_;
    $debugLevel = $level if $level;
    $class->Exporter::export_to_level(1, $class, $tag);
}

sub dPrintLog {
    my ($level, $msg) = @_;
    $level ||= $debugLevel;
    print { 5 => "L:$level $msg",
            3 => "$msg",
            1 => substr $msg, 0 ,1,
          }->{$level}, "\n";
}

__PACKAGE__
```

Interestingly, it doesn't work if you remove the @ISA line. You have to declare the `export` subroutine to make it work (based on my experiments, no documentation found):

```
sub export { Exporter::export(@_) }
```

or

```
*export = *Exporter::export{CODE};
```

or, even

```
sub export { goto &Exporter::export }
```

Comment: I am getting error when I run it.

Undefined subroutine &main::dPrintLog

On other hand, 
1.  I noticed that you do print {....}->{$level}, what is the "-->{$level} for?
2.  and "__PACKAGE__" at the bottom is for?

Comment: @hidden: What version of Perl and Exporter?

Comment: `->{level} ` is getting a value from an anonymous hash, like a switch. `_PACKAGE_ ` returns a true value like `1;` does.

Comment: This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread.  I don't know how to check the Exporter version.

Comment: I think I got it fixed coz I didn't put in the namespace.

Comment: use MyDbg (':all', 5); <-- I tried to change the "5" in to a variable like $dLevel, where I have specified $dLevel=1; but when I try to print the output from the "sub import" print $level, it say uninitialized variable.

Comment: @hidden: `use` runs in compile time, $dLevel is probably still empty - you'd have to populate it in a BEGIN block.